# FIFTPATH tonstarter contract

Tags: node.js, npm, smartcontracts, yarn-lock.json, ton

[Problem when exporting Fift.fif file to the tonstarter contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgkzL.png)

I tried export FIFTPATH=/Users\engue\Downloads\ton-master\ton-master\crypto\fift\lib
but it didnot give
It was expected to be exported to the contract and then execute npm run build command to compile main.fc